# Why is my Django Python Model not grabbing my nested json?

Tags: python, json, django, api, nested

I have been trying for a while to get a working API call to the blacklist website, hetrixtools (https://docs.hetrixtools.com/blacklist-check-api/), to just set up a simple API call, using an ip address, just so I can learn how to do API calls. I have followed guides on how to set up the seriliazers, models, forms, views and the html itself but I have not found any solution as to why it is not displaying the nested json. It displays the top level json perfectly fine, but when I try to nest my model it doesn't work. I have tried many=true, depth, readonly but none of them make a difference. What am I doing wrong to get the nested data?

views.py

```
def save_blacklist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubmitBlacklist(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ip = form.cleaned_data['ip']
            r = requests.get('https://api.hetrixtools.com/v2/' + settings.API_KEY + '/blacklist-check/ipv4/' + ip + '/')
            json = r.json()
            print(json)
            serializer = BlacklistCountSerializer(data=json)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                blacklist = serializer.save()
                return render(request, 'blacklists.html', {'blacklist': blacklist, 'ip': ip})
    else:
        form = SubmitBlacklist()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

serializer.py

```
class BlacklistNamesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = BlacklistNames
    fields = ('id','rbl', 'delist')


class BlacklistCountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blacklisted_on = BlacklistNamesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BlacklistCounts
        fields = ('id','status', 'api_calls_left', 'blacklist_check_credits_left', 'blacklisted_on')
```

models.py

```
class BlacklistCounts(models.Model):
   status = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   api_calls_left = models.IntegerField()
   blacklist_check_credits_left = models.IntegerField()


class BlacklistNames(models.Model):
    blacklisted_on = models.ForeignKey(BlacklistCounts, 
    related_name='blacklisted_on', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rbl= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    delist = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

It's just a project I want to do to learn how to API call, but if i roll this over to the actual API call system. I want to learn how to do it with this before I start working on the other API project. Please Help.

EDIT #1:

changed it so it would at least grab the data. If i print(serializer.data) after the serializer is saved it sends back this:

```
 "{'id': 5, 'status': 'SUCCESS', 'api_calls_left': 1917, 'blacklist_check_credits_left': 82, 'blacklisted_on': []}"
```

whereas the proper data, when i print it is:

```
{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'api_calls_left': 1917, 'blacklist_check_credits_left': 82, 'blacklisted_count': 10, 'blacklisted_on': [{'rbl': 'all.s5h.net', 'delist': 'http://www.usenix.org.uk/content/rbl.html'}, {'rbl': 'bl.mailspike.net', 'delist': 'http://mailspike.org/iplookup.html'}, {'rbl': 'bl.spameatingmonkey.net', 'delist': 'https://spameatingmonkey.com/lookup/149.202.170.60'}, {'rbl': 'cbl.abuseat.org', 'delist': 'http://www.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=149.202.170.60'}, {'rbl': 'rbl.efnet.org', 'delist': 'http://efnetrbl.org/remove.php?i=149.202.170.60'}, {'rbl': 'rbl.efnetrbl.org', 'delist': 'http://efnetrbl.org/remove.php?i=149.202.170.60'}, {'rbl': 'xbl.spamhaus.org', 'delist': 'https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/149.202.170.60'}, {'rbl': 'z.mailspike.net', 'delist': 'http://mailspike.org/iplookup.html'}, {'rbl': 'zen.spamhaus.org', 'delist': 'https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/149.202.170.60'}, {'rbl': 'talosintelligence.com', 'delist': 'https://www.talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=149.202.170.60'}]...}
```

This is done with just a simple call using some random ip '149.202.170.60'

Comment: Have you checked the else case of `serializer.is_valid()`? May be your serializer.is_valid() method is returning false.

Comment: I checked that - it is returning true that the serializer is valid - but not grabbing the nested model/serializer.